# vue eventbus - $on wont trigger the bus

Tags: vue.js, event-bus

I have looked at tutorials and read the papers but I don’t get it why my setup with eventbus does not work.

**In main.js**
I create a new instance of Vue

```js
/* create a eventbus*/
export const Bus = new Vue();
```

**In page1**

```js
import { Bus } from "../main";
```

I then have a click event that’s triggers a method

```js
methods: {
    moveData(inValue) {
      let valueToSend = inValue;
      console.log("valueToSend");
      console.log(valueToSend);
      Bus.$emit("emitAlbumTitle", valueToSend);
    },
  },
```

And `console.log` tells there nothing wrong with the method `moveData()`.

**In page 2.**
I try to listen to the busemit.

```js
import { Bus } from "../main";
  data() {
    return {
      id: this.$route.params.idAlbum,
      photoData: [],
      albumTitle: "",
    };
  },
```

In tried in `created()`, I have some other things going on there as you see, like an api-call but that should not affect this I think.

```js
async created() {
    try {
      this.photoData = await CallApi.getPosts(url + this.id);
      this.number = this.photoData.length;
      Bus.$on("emitAlbumTitle", (data) => {
        this.albumTitle = data;
        console.log("in the $bus");
        console.log(data);
      });
    } catch (err) {
      this.error = err.message;
    }
  },
```

But nothing in the console.logs in the Bus.$on starts, so that eventbus never starts?
I also have tried in `mounted()` hook

```js
mounted() {
  Bus.$on("emitAlbumTitle", (data) => {
   this.albumTitle = data;
    console.log("in the $bus");
    console.log(data);
  });
},
```

But same result.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Instead of using `(data)` have you tried using `data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `Receiver` component is not created until you click the link, at which point the event has already been emitted from `Sender`.

One solution is to delay the event emitted until the next macro tick (using `setTimeout` without a delay), as the `Receiver` component would be created in the current macro tick:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    async emitValue() {
      // wait til next macro tick
      await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r));

      EventBus.$emit("string-send", this.sendString);
    },
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/catching-event-from-event-bus-in-route-created-component-no4z9?file=/src/components/Sender.vue:629-699)

Comment: Thank you that works great! Is normal to use eventbus like this?

Comment: For this scenario, I'd recommend using route parameters instead, so that the data is in the URL. Vue Router could even parse the param and set a component prop.

Answer (score 1):

Try same as this works for me. Data will show in console on button click.

Here is the main.js file.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';

Vue.config.productionTip = false
export const eventBus = new Vue();
new Vue({
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

It is App.vue file.

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <div id="app">
      {{albumTitle}}
      <br>
      <button class="primary" @click="dataSend">send</button>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import {eventBus} from '@/main'
export default {
  name: "App",

  data: () => ({
    albumTitle: null
  }),
  created(){
   eventBus.$on("emitAlbumTitle", (data) => {
     this.albumTitle = data;
      console.log("in the $bus");
      console.log(data);
    });
  },
  methods: {
    dataSend(){
      eventBus.$emit("emitAlbumTitle", "some data")
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your toughts, but It´s one its in two different viewswhen the problem start